# How does transformation matrix and camera matrix change when indexing pixels from -1 to 1 instead of 0 to N-1

Tags: computer-vision, camera-pose

I'm trying to warp frames for view synthesis. Specifically, given a frame1 and poses of frame1 and frame2, I'm trying to warp frame1 to frame2's pose/view. For this, I'm indexing pixel locations as $[0,M-1]$ and $[0,N-1]$ for y and x directions respectively. My code is working perfectly (except occluded regions, which lead to holes).

I'm looking at [this View Synthesis paper](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPR_2020/html/Wiles_SynSin_End-to-End_View_Synthesis_From_a_Single_Image_CVPR_2020_paper.html). The [code](https://github.com/facebookresearch/synsin/blob/master/models/projection/z_buffer_manipulator.py#L38-L39) released by authors instead index pixels in the range $[-1,1]$. Directly using transformation and camera matrices is giving invalid transformed coordinates. Can you please explain how I should change the transformation and camera matrices so that it works for pixel indices in the range $[-1,1]$?

**More Details**:
I've implemented the warping in python using the below equations. Given a pixel location $p_1=[x,y]^T$

$$\hat{p}_1 = [x,y,1]^T$$
$$ P_1 = Z K^{-1} \hat{p}_1$$
$$ \hat{P}_1 = [P_1^T,1]^T $$
$$ \hat{P}_2 = T \hat{P}_1 $$
$$ P_2 = \hat{P}_2[0:3] $$
$$ \hat{p}_2 = K P_2 $$
$$ p_2 = \hat{p}_2[0:2] / \hat{p}_2[2] $$

$p_1$ is the point in frame1 and $p_2$ is the corresponding point in frame2. $P_1$ is 3D world point in the view of frame1 and $P_2$ is the same 3D point in the view of frame2. $T$ is the transformation between views of frame1 and frame2. $Z$ is true depth of point $p_1$ in view of frame1. K is the camera intrinsic matrix. hat ($\hat{p})$ is used for projective coordinates.

I compute the $4 \times 4$ transformation matrix $T$ as follows:
$$T = \begin{bmatrix}
R & t \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Where $R$ is the rotation matrix and $t$ is the translation.

The $3 \times 3$ camera matrix $K$ is given by
$$K = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{W/2}{tan(hfov/2)} & 0 & W/2 \\
0 & \frac{H/2}{tan(vfov/2)} & H/2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Where $H=W=240$ are the height and width of the frames, $hfov=60,\ vfov=45$

In short, what changes should I make to matrices $T$ & $K$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before attempting to answer this, let's first see what camera transformation matrix does. Consider the 3d point

$$ P_1 = [X_1, Y_1, Z_1]^T $$

Pre-multiplying by camera matrix gives

$$ K \cdot P_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{W/2}{tan(hfov/2)} & 0 & W/2 \\
0 & \frac{H/2}{tan(vfov/2)} & H/2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
X_1 \\
Y_1 \\
Z_1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$ = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{W/2}{tan(hfov/2)} X_1 + W/2 \\
\frac{H/2}{tan(vfov/2)} Y_1 + H/2 \\
Z_1
\end{bmatrix} $$

As we can see, $W/2$ at $K[1,1]$ scales $x$ value and the $W/2$ at $K[1,3]$ adds an offset. Thus, if $x \in [-1,1]$ then by this scaling and offsetting, we get $x \in [0,W]$.

Conversely, when $x \in [0,W]$, we should use the camera matrix as defined earlier. Hence when $x \in [-1,1]$, we shouldn't add the scaling or offsetting. Thus, only the camera matrix needs to be changed to

$$K = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{tan(hfov/2)} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{tan(vfov/2)} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$